# Mercurial extension to automatically generate .hgignore file?

Tags: mercurial

I have been thinking that it sure would be nice to have a command like "hg ignore" that would automatically add all untracked files to the .hgignore file.

Manually editing the .hgignore file is powerful, but when I am frequently creating new repositories it would be nice to be able to add only the files I want and then do an hg ignore to automatically have Mercurial ignore any others.

Does anyone know of any extensions that do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this once you've added all the files you need:

`hg stat --unknown --no-status >> .hgignore`

You can create a command to automatically generate your `.hgignore` using an [alias](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#alias). On a Unix-like system, add the following lines to your `.hg/hgrc` (or one of Mercurial's [other configuration files](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#files)):

```
[alias]
ignore = !echo 'syntax: glob' >> $(hg root)/.hgignore && \
          $HG status --unknown --no-status >> $(hg root)/.hgignore
```

This will give you a `hg ignore` command that will populate the `.hgignore` file with all currently unknown files, thus turning them into ignored.

On Windows, the syntax for the alias is:

```
[alias]
ignore = !echo syntax: glob > .hgignore && "%HG%" status --unknown --no-status -X .hgignore >> .hgignore
```

On Windows, you **must** run it in the root directory of the repository, otherwise the .hgignore file will be created in the current directory, which is probably not what you want.

The `!` syntax in aliases is new in Mercurial 1.7. In earlier versions you can add

```
[alias]
ignore = status --unknown --no-status
```

and then redirect the output of this command to the `.hgignore` file yourself:

```
 hg ignore >> .hgignore
```

You will then also need to take care of adding a `syntax: glob` line, if necessary (the default syntax is regular expressions).

Comment: Thanks that works, though it would be nice if hg ignore could do the same thing.

Comment: Thanks again.  I hadn't stumbled across alias' yet.  Neat!

Comment: Just tried the alias.  Unfortunately I am on Windows and the alias doesn't work.  Anyone know the syntax for the alias on Windows?

Comment: @ACRL: it's your lucky day. :) I was just about to add it.

Comment: That is feaking awesome.  Thanks!